# How to access YAML sublevel item in a nested variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Getting the error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

APP_CONFIG are loading fine.

```
account_type = 'sample'
allowed = APP_CONFIG['account']["#{account_type}"]['highlight']
```

Error points to 'allowed' variable line.

The method that I currently trying to is:

```
  def self.allow_highlight?(account)
    account_type = Account.find(account).active_pack # returning a string - OK
    logger.debug account_type.class # checked on console - OK
    allowed = APP_CONFIG['account']["#{account_type}"]['highlight'] # Error line
    if total_account_highlight > allowed
        false
    else
        true
    end
  end
```

Hope you understand. 
Any doubts, please ask me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us `logger.debug APP_CONFIG.inspect` and `logger.debug account_type`?

Comment: Account type: sample
Account type inspect: "sample"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first make sure that APP_CONFIG is being set in an initializer.

Secondly, this error will arise if APP_CONFIG, or account_type are nil, are you actually setting account_type right before that line like in your code, or is it being supplied from somewhere and actually does not contain a value? If account_type is nil, empty, or contains a value that is not supplied in your YAML file, it will throw an error. So, you should verify the contents of those two variables.

ALSO, if you just made APP_CONFIG in your initializers, make sure you restart Rails, as it only gets updated on initialization of the server

Comment: APP_CONFIG is loading fine, after setted, webserver was restarted and account_type variable is returning a string type as I expect.

Comment: solved. Was a type error. My mistake. I have defined 'accounts' and not 'account'. Thank you.

Comment: So in other words, the variables were not set, and it was indeed the account_type that was throwing the error, glad you got it!

Answer (score 1):

`account_type` should be string:

```
 allowed = APP_CONFIG['account']["#{account_type.to_s}"]['highlight']
```

or

```
 allowed = APP_CONFIG['account']["#{account_type.class}"]['highlight']
```

Comment: account_type is already a string. note on my comment beside it. also, account_type.class did not work. Thanks.

Comment: So why you are checking class in this line: `logger.debug account_type.class # checked on console - OK`?

Comment: I was just confirming the variable type. It's not really necessary.